# Spray-JSON in an Apache Zeppelin Notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spray, apache-zeppelin, spray-json

I am using `Zeppelin notebooks` to write a prototype for a `Spark Streaming` application. It receives small `JSON` messages via an event bus and I need to parse these in a (preferably) distributed manner. I chose `spray-json` to deserialize the individual messages, but I cannot seem to be able to get it working. I think believe that this is because `Zeppelin notebooks` are interpreted via some sort of REPL interface.

I directly copied this sample from the [docs](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes):

```scala
case class Color(name: String, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int)
object Color

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat4(Color.apply)
}
```

But it gives me the following output:

```
defined class Color
defined object Color
warning: previously defined class Color is not a companion to object Color.
Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.
<console>:75: error: value apply is not a member of object Color
 Note: implicit value colorFormat is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
         implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat4(Color.apply)
```

Is there another way that does allow me to deserialize my messages in a `Zeppelin notebook`? I am not bound to `spray-json`, but it does seem like a nice library.

Comment: Scala REPL has a paste-mode. Not sure if that is available in Zeppelin. Can you try `case class Color(name: String, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int); object Color;`

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-658 can you also try `:paste` in your interpreter ?

Comment: it's also scala-repl issue. There is a dupe for this one @philantrovert I don't know where it is now :/

Comment: `:paste` doesn't work, I should have mentioned that I tried that already. The solution provided by @philantrovert worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @philantrovert's comment, I was able to get it to work. The trick is to put the class and object declarations on the same line like this:

```
case class Color(name: String, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int); object Color;
```